# Networking in freedos

Tags: macos, networking, virtualbox, freedos

I have a VirtualBox with a freedos guest, OS X 10.6 host. I just want to get some files to the guest, whether it's through the web or locally. How would you accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Well apparently it's [pretty](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/freedos/index.php?title=Networking_FreeDOS_-_Introduction) [involved](http://www.brutman.com/Dos_Networking/dos_networking.html). I'll update this answer if I ever install the TCP/IP stack. For my purposes, actually, it might be simpler to communicate to the guest with VirtualBox's virtual CD or floppy drive.